# How to disable chromedriver "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" notification in Python?

Tags: python, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and trying to automatically click a button on a webpage, but the Chrome notification "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" pops up every time I run the program. How do I automatically disable this notification?

I saw this solution in Java:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

How would I write this block of code in Python?

Answer (score 3):

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options);
```

From first google resutlt: https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007189411--Chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notification